# Component.getElements() issue

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Trying to understand why I cannot access the results of `component.getElements()` in my helper method.

```
methodName:function(component, event, helper){

     console.dir(component.getElements());
     console.dir(component.getElements()[0]);
}
```

**The first console.dir() produces:**

[image]

The second `console.dir()` results in `undefined` and I have no idea why.

Comment: I tried to debug `component.getElements().length` and it is `0`